# ignore folder when pull request to master

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

We are using Azure Repository via WebBrowser. We have TEST branch:

```
TEST
Folder1
  |- folder0001
  |- folder0002
FolderA
  |- folderAAAA
  |- folderBBBB
```

and we would like always to ignore Folder1 when we pull to master and keep it like this:

```
MASTER
FolderA
  |- folderAAAA
  |- folderBBBB
```

Is there any option to achieve this and igonre Folder1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude Files on a Pull Request on Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271147/exclude-files-on-a-pull-request-on-azure-devops)

Comment: Currently there's no built-in feature to ignore the files from DevOps Pull Request. i added the details in the reply, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any option to achieve this and igonre Folder1?

Currently there's no built-in feature to ignore the files from DevOps Pull Request.

Entries in a `.gitignore` or `exclude` file have no effect on files that `Git already tracks`. Even you add ignore/exclude, the file will still be listed in Pull request.

[image]

You can vote on the [user voice ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ignore-files-when-reviewing-pull-request/908126) to raise its priority, which will engage the product manager to consider the feature.